# How to merge rows from one table to another row in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to merge rows from one table to another row in another table

Always value of the "amount" relating to the "name" is more than 10, but split into several pieces

If the value of the "amount" column is less than 10
collect all smaller than 10
bring together the values ​​of the column "description"
where has the same name

My goal is to not exist row "amount" below 10 in the new table

aka

I want this form table - 'table'

> id(1)    name(Name1)    description(Description1) amount(5.50)
>
> id(2)    name(Name1)    description(Description2) amount(5.50)
>
> id(3)    name(Name2)    description(Description1) amount(3.50)
>
> id(4)    name(Name2)    description(Description1) amount(3.50)
>
> id(5)    name(Name2)    description(Description2) amount(3.50)
>
> id(6)    name(Name3)    description(Description3) amount(10.00)

become in to this in a new table - 'newtable'

> Newid(1)    name(Name1)    description(Description1,Descripton2) amount(11.00)
>
> Newid(2)    name(Name2)   description(Description1,Description1,Descripton2) amount(10.50)
>
> Newid(3)    name(Name3)    description(Description3) amount(10.00)

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds a little like a Job for a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by`, [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and [`sum`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) for that.

Here's little sample:

```
SELECT
`name`,
group_concat(`description`) as `description`,
sum(`amount`) as `amount` 
FROM `table_name`
GROUP BY `name`
```

BTW, I forgot to ask: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select into newtable(name,newdesc,amt)
SELECT name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT description
                  ORDER BY id DESC SEPARATOR ' '), sum(amount)
     FROM table
     GROUP BY name;
```